# Can not call action from another controller MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So i have 2 controller in my controller folder, BookController and HomeController. I am trying to make a header and call it with partial call so i don't have to create it multiple time.

I made my header like this

```
<div id ="header">
<img src="Images/logo.png" id="logo" />
<div class="navbar">@Html.ActionLink("Home","index")</div>
<div class="navbar">@Html.ActionLink("Loan","index","LoanController")</div>
<div class="navbar">Student</div>
<div class="navbar">Book</div>
```

when i am click it home it can bring me to the main page, but when i am click loan i got error "Server Error in '/' Application". I have try to change the loan controller with "~/LoanController" and "~/Controller/LoanController" but i keep got the same error. Can somebody help me solve this?

Comment: Change LoadController to only Loan.

Comment: @jpgrassi woah it work! but why, how it work, i still don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the "Controller" part of the Loan. ASP.NET MVC does that for you.

```
<div class="navbar">@Html.ActionLink("Loan","index","Loan")</div>
```

Edit:
Behind the scenes MVC will look inside your Controllers Folder (which is the default folder for controllers) to a file that starts with "Loan".

In your case, you are using this overload of [ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String%29):

> LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String)

In which takes a controller name as the last parameter.